# Find the probability distribution function

Tags: probability-distributions

Let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables such that $Y|X = x$ is $\text{Exp}(1/x)$ and X is $\text{Gamma}(2,1)$ find the pdf of $Y$ and $E(Y)$

Comment: Hi Jack, this looks like a homework question. Can you show us what you have done so far?

Comment: The standard procedure works. Where is the trouble?

Comment: I calculate  P(Y=y)= integral from 0 to infinity P(Y=y|X=x)* fx(x)dx  = integral from 0 to infinity xe^(-yx)*1/(Gamma(2))*x * e^(-x) dx

Comment: I can't integral this function.  For expect value. I use E(Y|X=x)= integral from 0 to infinity yxe^(-x^2)dy. I still can't figure. I know once I get it. I will try E(E(Y|X)), because it is equal to E(Y)

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:*

$f_{Y|X}(y|x)f_X(x)=f(x,y)\\
f_Y(y)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x,y)dx$

Comment: integral from 0 to infinity xe^(-yx)*1/(Gam(2) * x * e^(-x) dx to get xe^(-yx)*1/(Gamma(2))* x * e^(-x) dx. How do I integral it? is this correct?